# Possible to rewrite for i in range loop on i, i+1 into for i in loop in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, for-in-loop

Is it possible to rewrite this loop below:

```
from typing import List 

def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray: List[int]) -> int:  
    product_list = []
    for i in range(len(inputArray) - 1):
        product_list.append(inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1])
    return max(product_list)
```

Into something like:

```
for i in inputArray:
    product_list.append(i, the thing after i)
```

Comment: Are you trying to use for a situation where you have something you can iterate over but not index?

Comment: oh no there are no such restrictions, I just wanted to see if it was possible since the syntax would look cleaner and more 'Pythonic' than using the indexing.

Comment: Well the generator solution was designed to allow for that possibility, but if you only need it with sequences that be indexed, then the zip solution looks like your best option - nice and succinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all adjacent pairs you can use `zip`

```
pairs = zip(inputArray, inputArray[1:])
```

Then you can use `max` and pass it another generator that multiplies the pairs to get the maximum sum

```
max(a * b for a, b in pairs)
```

Comment: Ok very cool, thanks, I did write a version of this with the zip but you have some optimizations from my version. So just to make sure I understand what's going on in your version: 

Zip only does for the smaller list so you don't have to lists of equal size
You can call max on the iterator returned from pairs and avoid turning things into lists.

Correct?
:

    ```tuple_list = list(zip(inputArray, inputArray[1:]))
    product_list = [(x*y) for x, y in tuple_list]
    return(max(product_list))```

Comment: Yes that's correct. `zip` returns an iterator of tuples that is the length of the smallest iterable passed to it. And yes, you can call `max` on a generator/iterator which is far more efficient than constructing lists that you will only use once

Answer (score 3):

If it's any help, you can make a generator function that will help you do this:

```
def pairs(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    val1 = next(it)
    for val2 in it:
        yield val1, val2
        val1 = val2

for x, y in pairs(range(10)):
    print(f"x={x} y={y}")
```

Gives:

```
x=0 y=1
x=1 y=2
x=2 y=3
x=3 y=4
x=4 y=5
x=5 y=6
x=6 y=7
x=7 y=8
x=8 y=9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` the sequence with a shifted version of itself:

```
seq = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

for i, j in zip(seq, seq[1:]):
    print(i, j)
```

Output:

```
a b
b c
c d
d e
e f
```

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten it by removing the intermediate list, but anything more will tend to obscure what you are doing.

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray: List[int]) -> int:  
    return max(inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1] 
        for i in range(len(inputArray) - 1))
```

Comment: Where can I go to read more about whatever you did here with inverting the for and the return statement? I have never seen this before, very cool.

Comment: They are called [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions). They make up the guts of "list comprehensions" but can be used elsewhere.

Comment: This is likely the most efficient solution because it doesn't attempt to create a copy of a portion of the list. While that may look pretty, it's actually not as straight forward as just using indices.